# Can twitter-bootstrap be used with jQuery alternative cash?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

## Preface:

To use functionalities like popovers and tooltips in twitter-bootstrap, [the official website](https://getbootstrap.com/) suggests to use jQuery along with popper.js and bootstrap's JS file.

I recently found out that there exists a very lightweight alternative to jQuery called [`cash`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash) by [Ken Wheeler](https://github.com/kenwheeler), and it uses same syntax as jQuery's.

## Problem:

I was wondering if it was possible and safe to use `cash` instead of jQuery (or its slim build) with bootstrap.

## What I have tried:

1. Checking whether popovers work by using `cash` in place of jQuery's slim build, but it didn't work out.

## Question:

Is there a workaround to making bootstrap work with `cash`?

Comment: If cash does not implement the methods that bootstrap needs, then you'd have to modify it to do so.  Or make a version of bootstrap that is written for cash (the library, not currency, though ..... ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by @Taplar, there would be a need to modify Twitter Bootstrap's code to work with cash library.

As Twitter Bootstrap is planning on rewriting its code with vanilla JavaScript, to work without jQuery, rewrite of code to enable Twitter Bootstrap to work with cash library is not very likely. See [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27993).

After rewrite of Twitter Bootstrap's plugins is completed, in case one wants to use cash library, it might well be used by separately linking it in web page.